# Print justified text in console

Tags: c#, string, console-application, string.format

What I would like to have is in the right side of the console to print a justified text. Exactly like all the console help commands do.

For instance the copy command: By typing `copy /?` a part of the result will be the following text (this text is in German because of the Windows language):

```
Quelle        Bezeichnet die zu kopierende(n) Datei(en).
 /A           Weist auf eine ASCII-Textdatei hin.
 /B           Weist auf eine Binärdatei hin.
 /D           Zieldatei kann entschlüsselt erstellt werden.
 Ziel         Bezeichnet das Verzeichnis und/oder Dateinamen der neuen
              Datei(en).
 /V           Überprüft, ob die Dateien richtig geschrieben wurden.
 /N           Verwendet den Kurznamen (falls vorhanden), beim Kopieren
              einer Datei mit einem Nicht-8Punkt3-Namen.
 /Y           Unterdrückt die Bestätigungsaufforderung beim Überschreiben
              vorhandener Zieldateien.
 /-Y          Fordert beim Überschreiben vorhandener Zieldateien zum
              Bestätigen auf.
```

In this case every text in the "right column" that exceeds the bounds will be continued at the beginning of column e.g: The `Ziel`

I have tried the following but nothing returned the desired result:

```
Console.WriteLine("{0,10}", "/s            The path from the source file (.ini file)");

Console.Write("{0,2}{1,20}", "/d", "The path where the destination file will be converted and copied (.xml file)");

Console.WriteLine("{0}\t\t{1}", "/s=d", "The path from the source file. The destination file will be automatically converted and copied in the same path with the source file.".PadLeft(100));

Console.WriteLine("{0,-10}{1,10}{2,-30}",
                    "/s            The path from the source file (.ini file)",
                    "/d            The path where the destination file will be converted and copied (.xml file)",
                    "/s=d          The path from the source file. The destination file will be automatically converted and copied in the same path with the source file.");
```

Comment: So what have you tried so far to achieve your desired behaviour?

Comment: `"".PadLeft()` and `string.Format({0,10}{1,50})`.

Comment: Please, update your question with some samples of your code and specify what's goes worng with it. Also see [How to Ask a good question on Stack Overflow](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: ok @AndyKorneyev done

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, as "quick and dirty" approach to write string having left indentation you can do some simple calculation, and write to console your string "part-by-part".

Sample code:

```
private static void WriteLineIndented(string line, int leftMargin, int width)
{
    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(line))
        return;

    for(int i = 0; i < leftMargin; i++)
        Console.Write(" ");

    if (line.Length <= width - leftMargin)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(line);
        return;
    }
    else
    {
        int position = Math.Min(width - leftMargin, line.Length - 1);

        while (position > 0 && line[position] != ' ')
            position--;

        Console.WriteLine(line.Substring(0, position));
        WriteLineIndented(line.Substring(position + 1, line.Length - position - 1), leftMargin, width);
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
string s = "The path from the source file. The destination file will be automatically converted and copied in the same path with the source file.";
WriteLineIndented(s, 10, 80);
```

Result:

> ```
>       The path from the source file. The destination file will be
>       automatically converted and copied in the same path with the source
>       file.
> ```

This approach can be easily modified to your situation - just write all you need, not only spaces in the first line.

Answer (score 0):

You can use \t in your print function which is a TAB and will be anywhere between 1 and 4 spaces

```
Console.WriteLine("Quelle\t\tBezeignet....");
Console.WriteLine("/A\t\tWeist...");
```

Produces the output you want.

I'll put in another answer:

With this method you can block print anywhere on your console:

```
    static int PrintBlock(int offset, int y, int maxLineLength, string text)
    { 
        //get the words
        var parts = text.Split(new char[] { ' ' });
        int i=0;
        var sb = new StringBuilder();
        for (; i < parts.Length; i++)
        {
            if (sb.Length + parts[i].Length < maxLineLength)
            {
                sb.Append(parts[i]);
                sb.Append(" ");
            }
            else
            {
                //this is a line
                Console.SetCursorPosition(offset, y);
                Console.Write(sb.ToString().Trim());
                sb.Clear();
                i--;
                y++;
            }
        }
        //print the last line
        Console.SetCursorPosition(offset, y);
        Console.Write(sb.ToString().Trim());
        y++;
        return y;
    }
```

You use it like this:

```
var text = "This is a text that exceeds the width of the console and must be displayed in a block for displaying help to a user";
var newOffset = PrintBlock(10, 2, 20, text);
```

The newOffset is the y position to start your next line.

Comment: this code works only with small texts. In my case I need a text that a little bit longer is as the console width.

Comment: Perhaps Console.SetCursorPosition(x,y) can help you. With some calculations you can produce block texts, but you'll have to take control over splitting your text yourself to avoid wrapping.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to do this is to use the verbatim string operator, `@`, like so:

```
            Console.WriteLine(
@"Quelle        Bezeichnet die zu kopierende(n) Datei(en).
 /A           Weist auf eine ASCII-Textdatei hin.
 /B           Weist auf eine Binärdatei hin.
 /D           Zieldatei kann entschlüsselt erstellt werden.
 Ziel         Bezeichnet das Verzeichnis und/oder Dateinamen der neuen
              Datei(en).
 /V           Überprüft, ob die Dateien richtig geschrieben wurden.
 /N           Verwendet den Kurznamen (falls vorhanden), beim Kopieren
              einer Datei mit einem Nicht-8Punkt3-Namen.
 /Y           Unterdrückt die Bestätigungsaufforderung beim Überschreiben
              vorhandener Zieldateien.
 /-Y          Fordert beim Überschreiben vorhandener Zieldateien zum
              Bestätigen auf."
              );
```

Note that when you type this in, you don't indent the string like you do normal program code (otherwise the spaces used for the indentation will actually form part of the string).

Alternatively, just use string concatenation like this:

```
Console.WriteLine
(
    "Quelle        Bezeichnet die zu kopierende(n) Datei(en).\n"+
    " /A           Weist auf eine ASCII-Textdatei hin.\n" +
    " /B           Weist auf eine Binärdatei hin.\n" +
    " /D           Zieldatei kann entschlüsselt erstellt werden.\n" +
    " Ziel         Bezeichnet das Verzeichnis und/oder Dateinamen der neuen\n" +
    "              Datei(en).\n" +
    " /V           Überprüft, ob die Dateien richtig geschrieben wurden.\n" +
    " /N           Verwendet den Kurznamen (falls vorhanden), beim Kopieren\n" +
    "              einer Datei mit einem Nicht-8Punkt3-Namen.\n" +
    " /Y           Unterdrückt die Bestätigungsaufforderung beim Überschreiben\n" +
    "              vorhandener Zieldateien.\n" +
    " /-Y          Fordert beim Überschreiben vorhandener Zieldateien zum\n" +
    "              Bestätigen auf."
);
```

Just add spaces to make it look like you want. There's no need to use string formatting specifiers if the strings are constant.

Comment: Thank you @Matthew but this is a non localized text. This would be a "great" temporary solution but not in my case. I prefer (if it's possible) something more formal

Comment: @nikogram It's just as simple if you want localised text - just add the multi-line text to the resources, and display it using Console.WriteLine(). In some ways, that's even easier. (Putting localised text into resources is the normal way to provide localised text.)